# How can I call a method at regular intervals inside of a CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android

**What my code does:** My activity has a `CountDownTimer` that starts when a user presses a button. When it completes, a sound is played. Here's the code:

```
public class PrepTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public PrepTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        updateSessionRemaining(millisUntilFinished);
        setPrepDigits(millisUntilFinished);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        session.setPrepRemaining(0);
        playSound();
    }
}
```

**What I'd like it to do:** I'd like the sound to play at regular intervals over the course of the timer (in addition to at the end). For example, in a ten minute timer, the sound might play every 60 seconds.

**Things I've tried:**

- Using an `if` statement inside the `onTick` method to check when `millisUntilFinished` is equal to a certain value (a multiple of 60 seconds, for example) and then running the method. This seems like the most straightforward solution, but I've found that the method is not triggered consistently (perhaps `millisUntilFinished` is skipping over the value I'm checking it against?).
- Creating separate, nested `CountDownTimers` and repeating with a `for` loop. The problem with this is that the code quickly becomes overly complicated and my intuition tells me that I shouldn't be running timers within timers.

**Question:** How can I run a method at regular intervals over the course of a CountDownTimer?

Comment: Use your first approach and make it a little more forgiving. Don't test for the 60s bounds. Test if the sound played in the current 60s interval.

Comment: Nice idea @tynn. I've had an idea to make another timer that will have a `tick` interval that you want to play sounds at, and it's `onFinish` can also play the sound. I think this is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking on this for a while I came up with a solution that satisfies my chief requirement of simplicity. Here's how to employ it:

*Declare two class-level variables*

```
private long startTime = 60000; // Set this equal to the length of the CountDownTimer
private long interval = 10000; // This will make the method run every 10 seconds
```

*Declare a method to run on an interval inside the `CountDownTimer`*

```
private void runOnInterval(long millisUntilFinished) {
    if (millisUntilFinished < startTime) {
        playSound();
        startTime -= interval;
    }
}
```

*And then call the method in the `onTick` method of the `CountDownTimer`*

```
// ...
@Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        runOnInterval(millisUntilFinished);
    }
// ...
```

And here's how it works: The `onTick` method of the `CountDownTimer` passes `millisUntilFinished` each time it ticks. Then `runOnInterval()` checks to see if that value is less than `startTime`. If it is, it runs the code inside the `if` statement (in my case, `playSound()`) and then decrements `startTime` by the value of `interval`. Once `millisUntilFinished` is lower than `startTime` again, the process starts all over again.

The above code is simpler than employing another `CountDownTimer` or a `Handler` and a `Runnable`. It also automatically works with any sort of functionality one might have added to the activity to handle `CountDownTimer` pauses and resets.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a countdown timer you can simply use a post delayed Handler and thread.At the end of the method post the handler with specified time interval as below code

```
Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call the method here
        myHandler.postDelayed(myThread, 1000);//calls thread after 60 seconds
    }
};
myHandler.post(myThread);//calls the thread for the first time
```

Comment: I will try this out. Can Handlers be paused (or at least discarded)? I need to include functionality for when the user cancels the timer before it has completed.

Comment: Seems that post delayed handlers need to be canceled and recreated, just like CountDownTimers. Thanks.

Comment: yes you can just set a boolean variable and set it on cancle click and check the condition before calling the postDelayed.